# how to get Rating value Flutter rating Bar to use in onPressed function

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have setup Flutter rating bar on my app, to give the possibility to my user to rate another user..
the code from the dependency [Flutter Rating Bar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar)

is as below

```
RatingBar.builder(
              initialRating: 1,
              minRating: 1,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              allowHalfRating: false,
              itemCount:5,
              itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
              onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                 print(rating);
              },
            ),
```

I want to get the value of the stars clicked and use it into a onPressed function to push value to the database.
Then I need to move the value into firestore with the function below:

```
CollectionReference addReview = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Consultant');
  Future<void> createReview() {
    return addReview
        .doc(widget.snapshot['id']).collection('Reviews')
        .add(
      { 'reviewsValue': rating,
      },
    ).then((value) => print("Reviews Added"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
  }
```

Comment: you can get selected value from onRatingUpdate()

Comment: No I am sorry I think you didnt get the question I need to call the function in onPressed but I think before I need to do something

Comment: At the moment I cant only print the value when the Star is clicked but I want to move the value to onPressed and perform only when onPressed function is done.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
step 1: declare variable (double)
ex:
`double _currentIndex=0;`
[image]

step 2: in the

```
onRatingUpdate:(rating){
    _currentIndex=rating;
    print(rating);
}
```

[image]

step 3: create buttom with onPressed method
ex

```
TextButton(){`enter code here`
onPressed(){
    print("current index ${_currentIndex}");
    //now you can put this value into your method saveData
}}
```

[image]

this is the result
[image]

Comment: Explanation looks good, but your image are not linked, Try proper linking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).